# Testing HTML body with inline attachments Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, minitest

I followed the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers) to some success. I'm currently testing the body of the email with a fixture (as documented). My email has inline attachments (images).

My test (see below) works for the most part, though the problem I am running into is when it compares the outputted HTML to the HTML I have in the fixture. Because the attachments are encoded, every generated email has a different image source (which fails the test, as the HTML is different (ie.)):

```
-  Made with <img src=\"cid:56e45e159c85_13fa6229fd9889725f@775f1d813fe9.mail\" width=\"10\" height=\"10\" > in Toronto, Canada
+  Made with <img src=\"cid:56e466f93993e_13f99bbda39989734@084c0dd0f919.mail\" width=\"10\" height=\"10\" /> in Toronto, Canada
```

Is there a way to test the HTML body succesfully? Is there a way for the encoded string to be the same everytime?

Thanks in advance!

```
require 'test_helper'

class LeadMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "confirmation_email" do
    email = LeadMailer.confirmation_email(leads(:lead), 'Varsity Heights').deliver_now
    assert_not ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
    assert_equal ['donotreply@yuhu.io'], email.from
    assert_equal ['email2@email.com'], email.to
    assert_equal 'Your request for a showing at Varsity Heights is confirmed.', email.subject
    assert_equal read_fixture('confirmation_email').join, email.html_part.body.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, I ended up using  assert_select_email do, then individually asserting each element (and just the presence of the image, excluding the link.